# DI constructor with optional parameters

Tags: dependency-injection, typescript, angular

My constructor has optional parameters and they seem to mess with the predominant way of doing DI.

```
constructor(public name:string, public age?:number, private _service:Service);
```

Typescript understandably doesn't like that I put a non optional parameter behind an optional one, furthermore the service doesn't get injected when the optional parameter isn't set. How do I solve that? I can't put it somewhere else in the constructor since I would be expected setting the service manually.

Is there something like field injection?

```
@Inject() private _service:Service;

constructor(public name:string, public age?:number);
```

Should I replace the optional parameters with default values? Any other suggestions?

**EDIT:**
As discussed below, I tried to inject a service into an object that isn't created by Angular's DI. This doesn't work. Since I can't create this class (model) using DI I now pass the service manually from the class that instantiates this objects.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Just add the [`@Optional()`](https://angular.io/api/core/Optional) decorator before the constructor parameter that should only be injected if there was a provider registered.

```js
import { Optional } from '@angular/core';    

constructor(public name:string, @Optional() public age:number)
```

Comment: I may be missing something, but "age" is not the thing I want to be injected. I create new object using the constructor like `new Person("Mike", 32);` and the `Service` should get injected independent from setting the age or not. Or do I just need to annotate every optional (TS=?) with @Optional()?

Comment: Not sure I fully understand your question. With `new Person("Mike", 32)` there is no dependency injection involved at all. DI is only involved when instances are created by DI itself. For example components and its dependencies are instantiated by DI. Can you please clarify?

Comment: "DI is only involved when instances are created by DI itself." I guess that's my "problem" or thing I didn't understand. I create the objects manually setting name and age using the constructor. I thought the DI would inject the other parameters with a registered provider. Guess that doesn't work.

Comment: Not if you do `new ...` then DI doesn't do anything. You could inject an [Injector](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/api/core/Injector-class.html) and then call `injector.resolveAndCreate(MyClass)`, but then all constructor parameters need to be resolvable from registered providers. You can't pass values to the constructor directly this way.

Comment: The `Person` class isn't injectable, therefore I this ins't an option. Person is just a model class with a save function that needs a service - which I would've liked to inject. I guess I need to restructure the class or get the service another way.

Comment: if you get `private _service:Service` injected to the component where you want to create a `new Person()` then you can just do `new Person("Mike", 32, this._service)` (still not sure if this is where you want to pass the service to though).

Comment: Thanks that's what I am doing now.

Comment: why @Optional() doesn't work well with super() call ? I have extended a class having constructor with optional parameters. But it doesn't seem to be optional when using @Optional

Comment: @Freak001 please create a new question with your code. It's hard to understand what exactly you try to accomplish without seeing a concrete example.

Comment: can @Optional tag be used twice in same constructor ??

Comment: @NavruzbekNoraliev sure, there is no such limitation

Answer (score 5):

If I understand correctly what you are trying to do, you need a service factory. See here: https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/dependency-injection.html#factory-provider

Basically,

```
class MyClass {
    constructor(public name:string, private _service:Service, public age?:number){}
}
```

And then

```
let myFactory = (_service: Service) => {
  return isAgeOk ? new MyClass(name, _service, age) : new MyClass(name, _service);
};
```

And then you should provide your service like this:

```
providers: [{ provide: MyClass, useFactory: MyFactory, deps: [Service]}]
```