# NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[Component-> MatDialogRef]

Tags: angular, typescript, dependency-injection, modal-dialog, angular-material

I'm using a component as a regular component reaching by routing, but I want it also to use it as the "target"  of modal dialog, when using injection into the component:

```
export class Component1 implements OnInit {
constructor(private service: <someService>,
public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<Component1>, //These 2 lines are used as 
                                            //injection from the opener
@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) {}
```

This is the code of the "opener":

```
openComponent1aSModalPage()
{
  Const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(Component1, {
  width: '70%',
  height: '70%',
  data: {property: propertyValue}
 });
```

I works when I activate the opener, but if I try to reach the same component using a regular routing, I'm getting:

> Error: Uncaught (in promise): NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[Component1 -> MatDialogRef]: 
>     StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[Component1-> MatDialogRef]: 
>       NullInjectorError: No provider for MatDialogRef!

How can I adjust that component to work in both modes ?

Comment: Hey, i havent much worked on Angular-material but I can try to understand your doubt better if u can create a demo on https://stackblitz.com.  I am unable to understand ur question clearly as of now

Comment: Try this https://github.com/angular/components/issues/8419#issuecomment-361972699

Comment: @Shashank Vivek - trying to clarify: In the beginning my component was a regular one, without the 2 injected params  in the constructor:public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<Component1>, 
@Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any) {}. Then - when using it as the target to the modal dialog - I added these 2 as the example showed my: https://material.angular.io/components/dialog/examples - now it works as modal, but when reaching it using regular routing- I assume it expect to get these 2 params, which are not injected. I assume I need to make them optional...

Answer (score 7):

I found a solution for the optional injected parameters in the component:
I've added @Optional() decorator before the constructor parameter (that should only be injected if there was a provider registered).

```
constructor(private service: <someService>,
@Optional() public dialogRef: MatDialogRef<Component1>,
@Optional() @Inject(MAT_DIALOG_DATA) public data: any )
```

I found the solution here:
[DI constructor with optional parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36446602/di-constructor-with-optional-parameters)