# How to define provider as optional when using non-constructor based DI in NestJS?

Tags: dependency-injection, nestjs

When using class-based DI in NestJS, we can use [@Optional decorator](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36446636/2446102) on constructor parameter.

But it isn't possible to use decorator if we use eg. [factory providers](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers#factory-providers-usefactory).

How can I achieve such functionality with NestJS DI?

Comment: I guess you must use `useClass`. I don't think `useFactory` has such capability

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This feature was added in Nest 9.

From [their docs](https://docs.nestjs.com/fundamentals/custom-providers#factory-providers-usefactory):

```
const connectionProvider = {
  provide: 'CONNECTION',
  useFactory: (optionsProvider: OptionsProvider, optionalProvider?: string) => {
    const options = optionsProvider.get();
    return new DatabaseConnection(options);
  },
  inject: [OptionsProvider, { token: 'SomeOptionalProvider', optional: true }],
  //       \_____________/            \__________________/
  //        This provider              The provider with this
  //        is mandatory.              token can resolve to `undefined`.
};
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same task recently.
My approach was to use moduleRef to resolve service safely.
My helper looks like that:

```
import { ModuleRef } from "@nestjs/core";
import { UnknownElementException } from '@nestjs/core/errors/exceptions/unknown-element.exception';

export function getSomeService(moduleRef: ModuleRef): SomeService | null {
  try {
    return moduleRef.get(SomeService, {
      strict: false,
    });
  } catch (e) {
    if (e instanceof UnknownElementException) {
      return null;
    }
    throw e;
  }
}
```

And then in factory you inject `ModuleRef` and call this helper.
Hope it will help)

Comment: It was fixed in Nest 9.